# Cant get the pseudo class before to work

Tags: css, background-image, pseudo-class

So here's what I'm trying to do,

I want to add a top background strip(of height 30px) just like how stackoverflow has using the pseudo class before. I know this can be done easily without it but I'm interested to know if it can be accomplished using the :before pseudo class.

Here's my code,

```
<div class="container">
//Other divs
</div>
```

And here's the css I'm using,

```
.container:before {
content: " ";
background-image:url(../images/head-bg.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
min-height:30px;
}
```

I read somewhere that `content: " ";` needs to be added for the pseudo class to work so I've added it with nothing in the quotes.

I've tried removing all the background code from the css and adding text within content quotes and it works. However, when I add the code for the background it doesn't.

I'll be grateful if anyone could point out the mistake I am doing with this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Or `position` perhaps. (not sure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `width` of `.container` to whatever you need it to be. You should probably also use `height` instead of `min-height`. The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are also `display:inline` by default, so in order for `height` and `width` to be applied you'll need to change `display`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezLeP/)

```css
.container:before {
    content: "";
    background-image:url(../images/head-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Also you can just use the empty string with `content`.